# Water behaviour under theoretical near-infinite pressure conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, water, fusion, thermoelectricity

I've asked a similar question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/what-happens-to-water-under-high-pressures-without-possibility-of-escape) but the answer given shows the behaviour of water under general conditions.

I'd like to know what the behaviour of water is like as pressures increase towards infinity without being able to escape it's confinement.. i.e. a ball of water at the core of a galactic mass.. maybe this question is more for theoretical physics since we can't really measure or experiment?

Comment: The answer you got there is likely the one you may receive here. You should really make sure you understand that one before continuing your search.

Comment: @AndréNeves that last answer is helpful for understanding the behaviour of water under relatively low pressures and temperatures. I'm looking to see what happens after the 'ice' cannot rearrange structure anymore yet pressure continues to increase.

Comment: I fail to understand what this would be. How much pressure would that be, in pascals? Here, take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(pressure)

Comment: Cheers, @AndréNeves. That's a good resource. The pressures I'm looking at fall between 10^11 and 10^16 Pa.

Comment: Then the top region of the chart mentioned in CSE (http://i.stack.imgur.com/RpaIc.png) is not "relatively low pressure", but in the order of magnitude you want. However, I don't know how very high temperatures (15 million K, core of Sun) would affect the state of the water.

Comment: research suggests that temperature has little effect on matter past a certain pressure. Density of matter is increased due to smaller and faster movements of sub-atomic particles.

Comment: In that case, that diagram would satisfy you completely. Ice XI would be the answer.

Comment: That's part of the answer, @AndréNeves but the steps that happen past that are most curious tho. 1 Tpa = ~ 10^12 Pa so the diagram only describes the characteristics at the beginning of my inquiry. What should happen past the ices, when pressures are strong enough to break bonds, and what entails from breaking these bonds?

Comment: Could you provide material to support the assumption that bond breaking would happen past that pressure? I'm just not sure that something very special would happen 4 orders of magnitude above 10^12.

Comment: Subatomic particles have pressure limits after which they degenerate. I'm unsure if the bonds between hydrogen and oxygen can break before this occurs even, considering that they would take up more room separate than together, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter#Electron_degeneracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the phase diagram for water:

[image: phase diagram]

The diagram shows us that at pressures around 1 terapascal (about 10 million atmospheres) ice is solid, at least up to 400 C. It has been predicted ([reference_1](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/papers/ice26.pdf), [reference_2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1941)) that at higher pressures, somewhere between 1.5 and 6 terapascals, solid ice will undergo an insulator to metal transition and display properties typically associated with metals (band structure, electrical conduction, etc.). That's around 15-60 million atmospheres.

But, if the pressure was to increase towards infinity, the behaviour of water (without water being able to escape its confinement, say a ball of water at the core of a galactic mass) would be very different...

Suffice to say, it doesn't stay water after a certain point. The intense temperatures created by the compression will cause the water to break apart, eventually no longer even having oxygen atoms due to nuclear reactions. Because we're talking about an externally applied pressure, the Chandrasekhar limit doesn't apply, so there is a point at which electrons and protons combine (when the [electron degeneracy pressure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B888M.jpg) is overcome) and a mass of neutrons remains. Neutrons themselves also have a degeneracy pressure (though we don't have good models to predict the exact pressure that has to be overcome). From here, we don't know what happens with as much certainty, but the formation of quark matter has been predicted.

Eventually, we reach a singularity. We can think of this as all the matter we had before being compressed into an infinitesimal volume with infinite density and our applied pressure ceases to mean anything. If we started with enough water, this would behave much like any other black hole, though [micro black holes](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/papers/ice26.pdf) are hypothesized to have some special properties.

Mentions: @ron @ Michael DM Dryden

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer with interesting topics to research. If it could be sound to assume that density would increase to match the assumed density of Earth's iron-nickel core, I wonder how electron degeneracy pressure affects magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the question is theoretical and so the response. Under enough pressure water will become a solid, regardless of temperature. That is, as far as it is still water. If pressure is high enough, the atoms will collapse and form neutron-degenerate matter (theorized to exist in the cores of neutron stars). I am not sure if there could be an intermediate mixed phase in between water and "neutronium" in which only one of the atoms collapese first (either H or O) and the other at a larger pressure.

Comment: Some studies suggest that at some pressure point between ice and fusion, water takes on metallic characteristics.

Comment: Would it be a solid in the core of the Sun (25 PPa, 15.6 MK)? It must be simple, but I couldn't figure that out.